# JPA: em.find doesn't load one to many collection

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I use EclipseLink as JPA provider. I have the following entity:

```
@Entity
class MyItem{
    @Id   
    int id;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy = "item",orphanRemoval = false)
    @MapKey(name="fooCode")
    private Map<String,Foo> foos;
    ...
}
```

When I do
`em.find(MyItem.class,id)` entity manager loads only MyItem class fields - it doesn't read @OneToMany collection.

I can solve this problem only using JPQL with join. But I want to make it without JPQL. How?

Comment: This should work, how are you testing that it hasn't been loaded, and are you putting annotations on both fields and properties?  The only way I can see this happening is if you put the FetchType.EAGER declaration on an annotation that isn't being picked up due to mixing access types.  That, or the EntityManager context you are reading from already has your entity in its cache with an incomplete foos collection

Comment: @Chris It doesn't work. I see that it doesn't work in log via sql query.

Comment: sorry, what doesn't work?  Show the log for your find operation - could the entity already have been loaded in your EntityManager context?  Find might only be hitting the cache and so not need to load the collection.  Try an em.refresh(entity) and see if your map is loaded, and if it is, make sure you are maintaining both sides of your relationship.

Comment: @Chris As I said, collection is not loaded, only direct fields are loaded. As I said I see it in SQL query.

Comment: I can't help if you don't show more, such as the log showing the query in question, and if you are unwilling to check your code to see if the entity was shoved in without its references before the find...  Please also note that looking at an sql query alone is not enough to tell if the references are there: they could have been previously loaded, and get loaded in a separate query anyway.